# Spotfire - Is there a way to update a data function input parameters based on the slider property control values?

Tags: r, ironpython, spotfire

I have to change the axis columns for the custom plot(a plot which is added using RinR) based on the selection from the Slider property control.

I found this below code to be useful as it allows me to set the input parameter for my data function but I am not sure how to get the Slider value and to set the input as a column instead of a String as shown in this example.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions import *

dataManager = Document.Data
dataFunction = None
for function in dataManager.DataFunctions:
    if function.Name == 'NewDF1':
        dataFunction = function
        for inputs in dataFunction.DataFunctionDefinition.InputParameters:    
            if inputs.DisplayName=="inputName":
                dataFunction.Inputs.SetInput(inputs,"String(\"HelloWorld\")")
```